# Conversion from int to unsigned short

Tags: c, type-conversion

this is a part of a C program that i didn't understand :

```
unsigned short twittlen;
int x;

x = atoi(argv[1]);
twittlen = x;

if(twittlen >= 64) {
    printf("Nope , You don't know about Integer");
    return -1;
}

if (x >= 64 ) 
    printf("you got it ");
```

My problem is how to find an int that is greater than 64 but when converting it to unsigned short it will be less than 64 ! 
I looked alot about limit of those types of integers even on stackoverflow but i didn't find the answer about this ! 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's not *that* many integers in an int, why not make a loop to try them all until you find one?

Comment: Note that it is a good idea to end messages printed to the terminal with a newline.  It helps ensure that the information is seen in a timely manner; the output may not appear until a newline _is_ printed, which could be a lot later than you expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you assign an `int` value to an `unsigned short`, *truncation* will occur.

Assuming `int` is 4 bytes and `short` is 2, you simply need to provide the program with a value greater than 64 whose lower two bytes are less than 64.

The maximum unsigned 16-bit value is 65535:

```
0x0000FFFF
```

So if you enter the number 65536:

```
0x00010000
```

When truncated to just two bytes:

```
0x0000
```

Is zero.